I can't understand how unsigned char _ [32] is used in this example
I am working on some examples of using zeromq and started reading the zeromq.h file to get into more detail.
I am buffled at the line where the zmq_msg_t is defined:
https://travlr.github.io/libzmq/zmq_8h_source.html#l00129
typedef struct {unsigned char _ [32];} zmq_msg_t;

For example you can initialize a buffer like this:
zmq_msg_t buffer = {0};

My question is probably about the compiler stuff I don't quite understand. Why do you define a structure like so:
typedef struct {unsigned char _ [32];} zmq_msg_t;

Is this a unsigned character array of 32 characters? What is the use of "_" ?
Thank you in advance.

_ is the name of the variable. It could have just as well been unsigned char Whatever[32];
In that case, the zmq_msg_t struct is padded to hold 32 bytes.
In some languages or some coding standards, a single underscore means "no name". A variable whose name is not important and will not be used, but its existence is needed. This is opposite to parameters, where their name can be omitted in function declarations: void Whatever(int, float);
Of course, there are also cases where names start with underscore, which are normally internal or technical and used by the compiler and should not be used by coders to define variable, function or parameter names.
As for why the structure is defined like that, it's an old-school style I personally dislike, but it's a personal opinion. It's not wrong or not recommended. On the contrary, it's quite used.
Normally, the way you declare a struct is
struct MyStruct
{
    // some fields
};

And you use it like so (in general, of course)
struct MyStruct myStruct;

There is also the possibility to alias it using a typedef:
typedef MyStruct SuperDuperAwesomeStruct;

And use it as you normally would.
SuperDuperAwesomeStruct myStruct;

You can also inline it:
typedef struct MyStruct
{
    // some fields
} SuperDuperAwesomeStruct;

So going back to where parameters can be omitted there is also another exception for anonymous unions or structs where you can skip their name and just typedef the structure itself:
typedef struct 
{
    // some fields
} SuperDuperAwesomeStruct;

Which is the situation in the header file you found.

Thank you for your answer. It cleared things up.

@Nick_K I also added some info about the syntax, in case you were curious about that as well.

"And you use it like so MyStruct myStruct;" Not in your first example, then it has the be struct MyStruct myStruct

Thanks, I did too many edits on it and forgot to update that example. Fixed it now.

A reason for having a struct rather than an array could be that it allows for direct assignment: zmq_msg_t a, b; ... a = b;. This cannot be done with an array.

Nitpicking:  You say "name can be omitted in function definitions: void Whatever(int, float);" — That's a declaration rather than a definition.  Also, in C23, you will be able to do as C++ has been able to do for aeons, and omit variable names in actual function definitions where the function has to have an argument to meet some interface requirement but won't actually use the argument: int Whatever(int key, float) { … code using key only … }.  In earlier versions of C, you'd have to write something like int Whatever(int key, float unused) { … code using key only … }.

@JonathanLeffler Regarding nitpicking, not at all. The idea is to get as much as possibly correct information so please, by all means, don't consider it as such. Not even I am perfect :) For the decl-vs-def, it might sound confusing, but I always considered definitions more of declarations as opposed to the implementations. But to avoid confusion, you're right, I'll change it. I didn't want to go into detail on C23 since I didn't check the papers superficially and only meant it of a more "exception to the rule". Thanks for the feedback :)

_ is simply a very poorly chosen variable name. _ is a valid symbol to appear anywhere in a variable name/identifier. So this is just a 32 byte array with a bad name.
Note however that it is bad practice to name identifiers starting with an underscore. From the C standard 7.1.3:


All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore
are always reserved for any use, except those identifiers which are lexically identical to
keywords.
All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file
scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.


In your specific case, the _ identifier sits in the member namespace so the above does not directly apply. Still a bad idea though.
And most importantly, identifiers should be meaningful, descriptive names.

Thank you for your answer. It cleared things up.
